# Can I make the Launchpad key (F4) on my new Macbook Pro toggle Mission Control instead?

Tags: macos, mission-control, launchpad

I will never use Launchpad, however I really like Mission Control. I'd love to disable the Launchpad feature and make my F4 key toggle Mission Control instead. F3 does that already, however I'd like to have both keys assigned to that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: Not really.

You can, however, enable the "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" option in the Keyboard preference pane:

[image: Keyboard preference pane screenshot]

... and then use [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to map <kbd>F4</kbd> to Expose.

[image: BTT screenshot]

By doing this, all functions of your current function keys won't work and you'll have to remap all of them using BTT as you like.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is **[FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/)**:
[image: FunctionFlip screenshot]

You can individually choose which keys you want as standard f-keys and which you want as the Mac-specific functions. In your case, "flip" the F4/Launchpad key, then assign F4 to launch Mission Control.

The only caveat is you cannot use both FunctionFlip and BetterTouchTool, as the developer of BTT [points out.](http://blog.boastr.net/?p=2310)

Answer (score 1):

A tool very similar to FunctionFlip is [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (formerly KeyRemap4MacBook). You **can** use it together with BetterTouchTool. Here’s how to remap F4 to Dashboard (which I still use and find useful) instead of the useless Launchpad:

[image: Karabiner settings]

Comment: this is the !!! answer. no need to use all F1..F12 keys as fn keys. Just don't forget to also activate the dashboard in the mission control settings in El Capitan because its deactivated there by default.